# Delaying results of a database by 25 minutes

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm new here and pretty much an eclectic coder at best so plz be gentle!

Data from a poker tournament is updated in realtime to a database, but we delay the video feed by 20-25 minutes because graphics (i.e. RFID card reader results, etc.) would result in viewers seeing things that players at the table themselves do not - like, everyone elses cards!

That's all handled by proprietary software called PokerGFX, so that part is fine.

But I would like to retrieve the data in the database (seperate from PokerGFX) at the same interval of delay as the video stream to implement a bot with Twitch API so people in Twitch chat can get relevent info like a particular players chip count, but what their chip count was 25 minutes ago, not the realtime data.

I can access the db with MySQL, php and use JS or whatever else is needed. It seems I'm wanting exactly opposite of what everyone else needs...SLOWER data retrieval, not persistent or FASTER LOL!

Thanks for any insight into this.

UPDATE: o but wait there's more: Things have changed, here's what I have:

SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE CurrTime > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
LIMIT 1";

is giving less than accurate results +-  2 minutes, so I need the most recent record at least 1 hour old. I have tried all kinds of things, interestingly enough, every google result brings me right back here! All of this data loads into an html that auto refreshes every 10 seconds, and I'm finding that if the database is not updated every 60 seconds or so, the html requesting the data goes blank.

Comment: Maybe https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html could be of interest to you?

Comment: Are you able to alter the table scheme or can you only read the data?
Are there already any timestamps or datetime fields which contain the create date?

Comment: Retrieve the details real time and store it in a database with a timestamp. Once you have the timestamp you can query the database you created and put a where clause where current_time - timestamp = 25 minutes.

Comment: LOL I have NO idea why I didn't think of that! This is a secondary database and I can construct it however I want, ofc I can just query WHERE current_time etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store a snapshot of the data in an intermediary database. Retrieve it in real-time, timestamp it and then display the data from the older snapshot (25mins ago). Also, depending on the structure of the original database you may be able to achieve this with only the original database.

Comment: I like the idea of an intermediary db that contains only the relevant data to avoid weird stuff, in other words, the ID would always remain the same with only updated info. Thanks!